# Get the List id (Guid) for a list by name in SP 2010 Programatically

Tags: list, custom-list, guid

If I pass in the name of a list is it possible to get the GUID id of that list and return it? I know you can get it on creation of the list, but I am assuming the list is already created.

Assuming i have the name test for a list can I pass test into a function that then returns me the Guid id of that list for use in other aspects?

Comment: What about using vba (Excel 2010)? Is it possible?

Answer (score 4):

The name of the list is meaningless as there can be lists by the same name all over a site.  You would need the Url to the list in order to be able to resolve it to a Guid.  However, the mechanics of this vary wildly depending on what you mean by "programmatically".  In PowerShell it would be something like this and the server object model would be similar.

```
    [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint")
    $site = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite]($UrlTolist)
    $web = $site.OpenWeb()
    $list = $web.GetList($UrlToList)
    $list.ID
    $web.Dispose()
    $site.Dispose()
```

Getting the ID via Web Services or the client object model would be completely different.

Answer (score 2):

in the Server object model you can use.

```
SPList list = SPWeb.Lists.TryGetList("YOurListName");
```

then you would already have the SPList the you can get the guid by using the ID property of the SPList

```
SPList.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Server Object Model

```
Guid listGuid = spweb.Lists["ListName"].ID;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the List name I assume u must have the Url of the List as well and you could use it as below:

```
web.GetListFromUrl("your list url").ID;
```